# pass Variable to Restful

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest

my question is: How can i pass variable(java script) to a rest apllication

This one of my functions in my controller.js:
This code sampel work, but i cant use my var email and password. 
at the moment i use the url path log me in(url : 'rest/ab/einloggen/t@rt.de/22'). But how can i use var email(t@rt.de) and passwort(22).

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$http){
$scope.submit = function(){
var email = $scope.username;
var password = $scope.password;


$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'rest/ab/einloggen/t@rt.de/22'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   console.log(data);
   if(data=="true"){
        $location.path('/eingeloggt');
        console.log("lalala");  
   }


}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        });

};

});
```

Here is the login rest function:

```
@Path("/einloggen/{username}/{passwort}")
@GET
public String einloggen(@PathParam("username") String Username,@PathParam("passwort") String Passwort)
    {
        // Bekomme die strings
        Business b = new Business();
        boolean test =b.einloggen(Username, Passwort);
        //Return einer JSON
        String ersatzBool ="false";
        if(test==true){
            ersatzBool="true";
        }

         return ersatzBool;

    }
```

Comment: You have this snippet already: `url : 'rest/ab/einloggen/t@rt.de/22'`. Notice something? I'll help you: email and password are already part of the string. So if you want to use variables for email and password you might want to construct the url using string concatenation, e.g. something like `'rest/ab/einloggen/' + email + '/' + password` (note this is not necessarily correct syntax, it's just meant to give you an idea).

Comment: ohhh yeah right sound right. I will try tis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass data to webapi you can use
'POST' instead of 'GET', In the below example I have passed json data {id: 2 }
and getting response as a list of products, In the api post method id 2 is available.

```
 $http.post('http://localhost:1011/productDetails', { Id: 12 }, {
              headers: {
                  'Content-MD5': '917200022538',
                  'Accept': 'application/Json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/Json'
              }
          }).then(onUserComplete, onError);

    var onUserComplete = function (response) {
        $scope.Products = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function (reason) {
        $scope.error = "Error while fetching records.";
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I had to do while communicating with a server(CMS application - Contentstack) using Restful api's, one striking difference would be I had to use authtoken.

```
$http({
    url: siteUrl,
    method: methode,
    headers: {
        access_token: auth_token,
        api_key: site_api_key,
        Accept: data_type, // --> 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
    },
    data: dataBody
}).then(function (resp) {
    console.log('success ', resp);
    callback(resp);
}, function(err){
    console.log(err, "error");
});
```